# How can I go directly to a nested state with the back button to its parent state in Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic Framework 1.0.0-beta.14. In my case, I want to go to a nested state directly, and have the back button to its parent on the header. This sample http://codepen.io/TimothyKrell/pen/bnukj is exactly what I want to achieve. I've tested it in the latest version (1.0.0-beta.14), but it doesn't work. Here is a part of its code:

```
angular.module('stateBackButtonIonic', [])
    .config(function($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$ionicViewService', function($delegate, $rootScope) {
            var registerFunction = $delegate.register;

            $delegate.register = function() {
                var viewHistory = $rootScope.$viewHistory,
                    rsp = registerFunction.apply(this, arguments);

                if (viewHistory.forcedBack) {
                    rsp.navAction = 'moveBack';
                    rsp.navDirection = 'back';
                    viewHistory.forcedBack = null;

                    this.clearHistory();
                }

                return rsp;
            };
            return $delegate;
        });
    })
    .directive('prNavBackButton', function($animate, $rootScope, $sanitize, $state, $ionicNavBarConfig, $ionicNgClick) {
        var backIsShown = false,
            viewHistory = $rootScope.$viewHistory;

        function backViewIsPresent() {
            return viewHistory.backView && viewHistory.backView.historyId === viewHistory.currentView.historyId;
        }

        function parentStateIsPresent() {
            return !$state.$current.parent.abstract;
        }

        // Everytime history changes, check if the back button should be shown
        // We ignore ionic's data saying whether it should be or not, favoring our own logic
        $rootScope.$on('$viewHistory.historyChange', function() {
            backIsShown = backViewIsPresent() || parentStateIsPresent();
        });

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: '^ionNavBar',
            compile: function(tElement) {
                tElement.addClass('button back-button ng-hide');

                var hasIconChild = !!(tElement.html() || '').match(/class=.*?ion-/);

                return function($scope, $element, $attr, navBarCtrl) {

                    // Add a default back button icon based on the nav config, unless one is set
                    if (!hasIconChild && $element[0].className.indexOf('ion-') === -1) {
                        $element.addClass($ionicNavBarConfig.backButtonIcon);
                    }

                    //Default to ngClick going back, but don't override a custom one
                    if (!angular.isDefined($attr.ngClick)) {
                        $ionicNgClick($scope, $element, function() {
                            if (backViewIsPresent()) {
                                navBarCtrl.back();
                            } else if (parentStateIsPresent()) {
                                viewHistory.forcedBack = true;
                                $state.go('^');
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    //Make sure both that a backButton is allowed in the first place,
                    //and that it is shown by the current view.
                    $scope.$watch(function() {
                        if (angular.isDefined($attr.fromTitle)) {
                            $element[0].innerHTML = '<span class="back-button-title">' + $sanitize($scope.oldTitle) + '</span>';
                        }
                        return !!(backIsShown && $scope.backButtonShown);
                    }, ionic.animationFrameThrottle(function(show) {
                        if (show) {
                            $animate.removeClass($element, 'ng-hide');
                        } else {
                            $animate.addClass($element, 'ng-hide');
                        }
                    }));
                };
            }
        };
    })
    .directive('ionTabs', function($rootScope, $state) {
        var viewHistory = $rootScope.$viewHistory;

        function getTabRootState(state) {
            var isRootState;

            if (state.parent.self.abstract === true) {
                isRootState = state.self.name;
            } else {
                isRootState = false;
            }

            return isRootState || getTabRootState(state.parent);
        }

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: 'ionTabs',
            link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
                var selectTab = ctrl.select;

                ctrl.select = function(tab, shouldEmitEvent) {
                    var selectedTab = ctrl.selectedTab();

                    if (selectedTab && selectedTab.$historyId == tab.$historyId) {
                        if (shouldEmitEvent) {
                            viewHistory.forcedBack = true;
                            $state.go(getTabRootState($state.$current))
                        }
                    } else {
                        selectTab.apply(this, arguments);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

Do you guys have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: codepen link isn't working

Comment: @mfink you're right, my bad. It's working now.